# How to get only the strings that come after certain characters?

Tags: python

if i have this code

```
import csv
txt_file = r"input.txt"
csv_file = r"Good_data.csv"
in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = ',')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w'))
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

this code will move the strings from txt to excel but i want only the strings that come after the letter Y to be moved 
for example this is a line in input.txt

```
u'gY': -0.009,Y'gm': 0.0011, Y'ay'
```

TQ

Comment: in what format you want to arrange the data?

Comment: doesn't look messy, looks like JSON, not sure if it's malformed or you just posted it like that

Comment: Looks like you have dictionaries, you can use pandas to get a dataframe ... here is the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: i am sorry i didnt specify how i want to arrange it ...i wanna arrange it by printing only the words that come after the letter u

Comment: What letter `Y`? Show a sample of `input.txt` that enables us to understand your question.

Comment: @LutzHorn i just edited the question hopefully its clearer now

Comment: @Johnsteven. There are three Y's in the sample you provided. Which ones are relevant? Please show some lines from `input.txt` *exactly as they appear in the file*. You should also show what you expect to get as output.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Positive Lookbehind (?<=Y)`  :

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<=Y)'(\w.+?)'"

string="u'gY': -0.009,Y'gm': 0.0011, Y'ay'"

print(re.findall(pattern,string))
```

output:

```
['gm', 'ay']
```

regex information:

```
Positive Lookbehind (?<=Y)
Assert that the Regex below matches
**Y** matches the character Y literally (case sensitive)
**'** matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group **(\w.+?)**
**\w** matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
**.+?** matches any character (except for line terminators)
**+?** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
' matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
```